# Output the count from two Models in the same view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    price = models.FloatField()
    upload_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('upload_time',)

 class Status(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    album_id = models.IntegerField()
    favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    purchase = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    history = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_id
```

in a `ModelViewSet` I wrote like this:

```
class index(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
```

[image]

As the image shown above, I need output the count of purchases of each `Album`, e.g. `Album` 1 has been purchased 4 times, `Album` 3 has been purchased 1 time.

But right now, my index view only generate the fields in `Album` data model.

What should I do to implement this, add the purchase number for each `Album`? Need your help...

Comment: You need to make actual database relationships between your two models otherwise its going to be an absolute nightmare to make a query to do this if at all possible.

Comment: @Sayse Could u pls be more specific if u got time?

Comment: Storing an `album_id`  on the `Status` model just isn't going to suffice. Use the relationship field type for your requirements

Comment: @Sayse like this? album_id = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='') then, how to count the purchase number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something like this to your serializer class to count it:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    purchase_count =  serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)


    def get_purchase_count(self, obj):
        return Status.objects.filter(album_id=obj.id, purchase=True).count()
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect your Album and User models as many to many relation:

   ```
   class Status(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey('userapp.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       album = models.ForeignKey('albumapp.Album', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
       purchase = models.BooleanField(default=False)
       history = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   ```

   Don't forget to apply migrations.
2. Do query with annotation:

   ```
   queryset = Album.objects.all().annotate(
       purchase_count=Count('status', filter=Q(status__purchase=True)),
       favorite_count=Count('status', filter=Q(status__favorite=True)),
       history_count=Count('status', filter=Q(status__history=True)),
   )
   ```
3. In attributes `purchase_count`, `favorite_count` and `history_count` you'll have corresponding values.

Comment: thx a lot, I think yours should be another solution if I add the relationship as @Sayse suggested above.